Authentication fails with 404 on Azure SWA when trying to access /.auth/login/auth0
I am trying to configure Azure static web app custom authentication on a React app, but after trying multiple options still, I am srill unable to figure out the issue.
I have configured SWA with staticwebapp.config.json for custom authentication using Auth0 but it always throw 404 error when I access /.auth/login/auth0
repo link for reference.
Also I dont find any relevant logs on SWA.
I tried the following

copying the config.json into build folder.
Tried available public git resources.


Check this Link Once.

I have added Custom Authentication (Auth0) Configuration code to the provided react app repo for Azure Static Web app.
I run the below command to install auth0 package:
npm install @auth0/auth0-react

Below is the complete code which will be used to implement the authentication in react-app.
App.js:
import React from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
function App() {
  const { loginWithRedirect1, logout, user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>React App with Auth0</h1>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <div>
            <p>Welcome, {user.name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => logout({ returnTo: window.location.origin })}>
              Log out
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect1()}>Log in</button>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import config from './auth_config.json';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <Auth0Provider
    domain={config.domain}
    clientId={config.clientId}
    redirectUri={config.redirectUri}>
       <App />
  </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();

auth_config.json:
{
    "domain": "<DomainName>",
    "clientId": "<ClientId>",
    "redirectUri": "<StaticWebappUrI>"
 }  

staticwebapp.config.json:
{
    "auth": {
      "identityProviders": {
        "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
          "auth0": {
            "registration": {
              "clientIdSettingName": "<ClientId>",
              "clientCredential": {
                "clientSecretSettingName": "<ClientSecret>"
              },
              "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
                "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "https://<Auth0Domain>.us.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
              }
            },
            "login": {
              "nameClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
              "scopes": ["openid", "profile"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

Even I got the error while logging into azure static web app.
Then I tried to Configure,

The Auth0 Client Id and Client Secret to Environment variables of
static web app as shown below:



In Auth0 Application settings I set the Application Type is Single
page Application. Application Login URI, Allowed Callback URLs,
Allowed Logout URLs and Allowed Web Origin is set to the Azure Static
Web App URI https:// staticwebappuriName. azurestaticapps. net as
show below.



Azure Static Web App Output:



Thanks for the reply really appreciate.
The problem was actually with the hosting plan, I had chosen free instead of standard and therefore the custom auth wasn't working.
But I would need help on logging the trace, I tried enabling the application insights after attaching a managed function but the application insight automatically disables. Do you have any idea? Does it also need a standard plan. I want to actually check what token validation fails on the azure static web app

@Sagar Nayak I am also using free plan, but I am able to add custom auth.

@Sagar Nayak Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
